# ¿Se puede insertar números comprimidos en postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

soy un novato usando postgres y tengo como fuente, para algunas tablas, ficheros de longitud fija con numéricos empaquetados (cobol comp-3) y quería saber si es posible insertarlos directamente o si hay que hacer algún tipo de conversión antes.

Comment: Revisa https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html, tiene un tipo binary pero entiendo es solo para un formato específico del motor, para levantar ficheros de COBOL seguramente vas a necesitar un proceso intermedio que lo convisrta en un CSV y desempaquete los valores numéricos y seguramente de fecha.